# Using the CollectionViewSource Class in Windows Store Applications

Tags: windows-runtime

How can I work with collection changes when working with CollectionViewSource? I just can't figure out how to keep the sorting and have it show changes without having to 'manually' set the source again. Somebody please just put me out of my misery and let me know how and if this can be done =)

Comment: If you have to set the Source property again, it sounds like a binding issue. Can you add your XAML to the question, please?

Comment: Can you share some code or write more about what you have tried? CollectionViewSource in Windows 8 XAML does not have built in support for sorting, but you can manage the sorting on the view model side, no?